# htaccess password protect but not on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost

I have set up a dev site and want to password protect it so only validated visitors can view the site. All well and good. I am getting annoyed, on my local version, entering my username and password. So, without changing the htaccess file between my local copy and the one on the dev site, how do I password protect the site but allow myself access without having to enter my username and password?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick..

```
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy

Comment: Not sure why, but when I used this the authentication totally breaks down and lets anyone see the protected area... I mean it works on my dev site as it should because my IP is 127.0.0.1, however when I publish it to the live server, it still just lets me in... not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out a cool way to seperate Linux from Windows password files (because I develop in windows and then release to a linux production server).

I just wrote a php script with phpinfo(); on our local and prod server and found the apache module 'mod_win32' to seperate the two of them.

```
<IfModule mod_win32.c>
    AuthUserFile C:\xampplite\your\windows\path.passwd
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_win32.c>
    AuthUserFile "/your/linux/path/.passwd"
</IfModule>
AuthName "Please Login"

RewriteEngine On
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 2):

Example for Windows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile C:/Apache24/htdocs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from localhost
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you are fine entering the password on the dev site - put the auth directives in a VirtualHost on the dev site rather than in the .htaccess file - this way your auth is processed at a server level rather than a directory level.

Also, most modern browsers will probably save your password for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281277/htaccess-allow-localhost-problem) you could use `allow from` to allow access from a specific host.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache 2.4 you can also surround your password protection by checking against the [HTTP_HOST](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm) environment variable like this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'localhost'">
    # Your password protection code
</If>
```

See also the answer from Mark Fox to the question about [accessing the environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269755/can-htaccess-read-a-server-environment-variable-set-in-apache).