# Set a Top Level or Super Duper Global Variable in PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to make a Top Level Variable in PHP? Like Defining in `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`? To be included in each `.php` file?

I would love to define BasePaths and some other variables there if possible. I am currently making some `init.php` and including 'em on top if each file.

Comment: You'd probably want to create a config file, and then have every other file include it at the top.

Comment: @StuartWagner, Yeah that's what I am doing now. I think that's very boring.

Comment: Sometimes boring is the best approach :P

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php

Comment: @tika, I think not yet. But, I would love too as well.

Comment: @DavidJacquel that sets Environment, Right? Is it possible to set a variable as I asked?

Comment: @tika Yes, the question gives a good example of setting and retrieving an environmental variable. That should suit your needs.

Comment: Do you really mean variable, not constant? For something like variables you need to store its value in a session, a file, a database or on a service which is made for this purpose. For constants see David's answer

Comment: @DanielAlder, Nope. A Constant is Enough. I can point them to a file and make some globals. That's fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your working with a multi entry point application, if you want to avoid including your configuration file, you can use the [php's autoprepend functionality](https://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). This will automatically include a file for you without the need to do a `<?php require('init.php'); ?>` in each of you entry points.

And you can find a [good advice here](http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess).

Comment: this is also a very nice option if we just want to include :)

Comment: How to achieve something like: 
`php_value auto_prepend_file {DOCUMENT_ROOT}."/init.php"`

The `.htaccess` file and `init.php` are in the same folder.

Comment: Give the full path `php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/utilities.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, reference and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php), I am posting this answer future references for people in community:

Setting on `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv VAR_NAME varValue
```

Also, worth mentioning:

```
SetEnv 'VAR NAME' 'var value' #Accepts Space with Quotes
```

Getting them on PHP files:

`getenv('VAR_NAME')`

More reference on : http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

> If you are looking just to `prepend` a file on top of all the files and define all variables there, see `David Jacquel's` answer. That's cool. ;)