# TYPO3: Setting Development via .htaccess

Tags: apache, typo3

My `TYPO3_CONTEXT` didn't work well.
I tried enabled the development mode in `.htaccess` as follows:

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development
```

Even after clearing the caches, I still get under *Application Context: Production*.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: How do you define it in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Does [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php) help?

Comment: SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development

Comment: Updated your question. Did you check the link? I.e., [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html).

Comment: I checked the link and I'm actually checking if mod_env is enabled

Comment: I didn't solved the problem, but the cause is that mod_env is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, if `mod_env` isn't available for you.
Put the following snippet in your index.php before `call_user_function() ...`

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com') {
   putenv('TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development');
}
```