# How to pass REQUEST_URI from htaccess to PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a redirect URL where pass `REQUEST_URI` from `.htaccess` to PHP file.

Here is my files structure:

- `index.php`
- `.htaccess`
- `folder/index.php`

If the URL is `http://example.com/?something`

I want to pass `%{REQUEST_URI}` full URL from `.htaccess` to `folder/index.php` and retrieve it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

My `folder/index.php`:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

`.htaccess`:

**UPDATED:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/index.php$
    RewriteRule .* /folder/index.php [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

I expect to echo `REQUEST_URI` in PHP file but always give external server.

Comment: What do you mean by "it always give **external server** ?

Comment: when type mydomain.com/?something it gives 500 external server page instead of passing the REQUEST_URI from htaccess to php file.

Comment: Usually you don't need .htaccess to get that variable value.
`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` gets it. Just place the script containing that instruction in _/public_html_ or similar directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass `%{REQUEST_URI}` full URL from `.htaccess` to `folder/index.php` and retrieve it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

You can't actually do this (but I don't think this is what you are trying to do - or even want to do - anyway). To clarify...

The PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is populated by PHP and this cannot be overridden.

Whilst `%{REQUEST_URI}` (the Apache *server variable*) and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (the PHP superglobal) are *similar*, they reference different values:

- `%{REQUEST_URI}` (Apache server variable) - references the URL-path only (no query string). The value is %-decoded. If the request is rewritten, then this is updated to contain the rewritten URL, not the URL of the initial request.
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (PHP superglobal) - Holds the initial URL-path **and** query string the user requested (not the rewritten URL). The value is not %-decoded.

If you really do want to reference the Apache server variable `REQUEST_URI` in PHP then you need to explicitly pass it (perhaps as an environment variable or query string) - but depending on *when* you "pass it", you could end up passing different values. And either way, this will not change the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which, as mentioned above, is controlled by PHP.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APACHE_REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]
```

And reference this in PHP as `getenv('APACHE_REQUEST_URI')`.

---

**UPDATE:**

By the sounds of it, you probably want something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ folder/index.php [L,NE]
```

This *internally rewrites* any request for the document root, that contains a *query string* (everything after the `?`) to `/folder/index.php`. When the query string is absent then `index.php` in the document root is served as normal.

Then, in `/folder/index.php` you simply access `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to access the query string (the string to redirect to).

Comment: "i tried your code but does not work" - the code I posted _does_ work, but it isn't meant to solve your specific problem. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? What is it you are actually trying to do? "I want to pass the full `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to my PHP file" - this doesn't make sense. As I stated above, this is generated automatically by PHP, there is nothing to "pass"? And there is no need to parse this to get the "url after `?`" - this is called the _query string_ and is already present in the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to. I've updated my answer. (Asking about _passing_ `REQUEST_URI` would seem to be a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).)

Comment: OMG!! Yes, this one works great!! thank you soo much, but why it is red herring? because i'm working with it and works but just don't know how to acheive the same result you did with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] using htaccess, do you know?

Comment: Glad it works, you're welcome. Please mark it as "accepted" (checkmark below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful.

Comment: It was a "red herring", because you were asking about a perceived solution, instead of the actual problem. " just don't know how to acheive the same result you did with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] using htaccess, do you know?" - I'm not sure what you mean; that's what this code already does. (?)

Comment: Ok, marked as asnwered :) i'm just asking if possible to acehive it by request $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in my php file instead of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] Do you have another solution for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to pass it from main index to my php file?

Comment: The `.htaccess` solution would be the same if using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Except you would need additional PHP code to parse the query string from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP variable.

Comment: That URL does not resolve for me? No changes are required for `.htaccess`. Using that code, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would return a string of the form `/?http://google.com` for such a request - you would then need to extract everything after the first `?` (to get the same value as is already available in the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable). What is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returning for you?

Comment: That suggests you have an error in your PHP code that parses the URL. (As stated above, that is the expected value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - it doesn't look like you code is doing anything?)

Comment: "I think the code and extract url works fine" - How can it be working fine? The result wouldn't be `/?http://google.com` if it was working fine?! It doesn't have to be a "syntax error", it can be a "runtime error" - when you don't get the expected output, given a certain input. Add your PHP code to your question.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` that your script is seeing? That will tell you whether `.htaccess` is working OK or not.

Comment: But that is correct? You'd then extract the query string with something like `parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_QUERY);` or `substr(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?'),1);` - both result in the same thing, eg. `http://google.com`.

Comment: yes with your code works fine now, thank you so much for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable.

`.htaccess`

```
SetEnv RURI %{REQUEST_URI}
```

`index.php`

```
<?php $requestURI = getenv('RURI'); ?>
```

[Set an environment variable in .htaccess and retrieve it in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php)

Make sure `mod_env` is enabled in Apache.

Comment: tested but does not work, you have to know that i use ?something in main index.php and not folder/index.php i think the way i did it is 50% correct but don't know what missing to make it fully work.

Comment: Try to put the `SetEnv` before the `RewriteCond`.

Comment: sorry, but does not work. any way to get it in my php file folder/index.php using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?