# Http to https error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: php, linux, apache

My problem is specific because site redirects are a bit complicated
in the www folder
with php codes

index.php

```
 <?
header("Location:https://www.example.org/kods_bird/uye/?fsx=@");
?>
```

this redirect exists and the kods bird folder has the same redirect

my .htaccess,
Located in the www folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Why is ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error?

Which solution am I looking for?

```
url request:http://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
url redirect:https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there was logical issue which caused looping inside rules.

So try this fix:

```
# rewrite non https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if https but without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

let's analyze 1st situation:

```
http://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

will be handled by first rule (https off) which will redirect to with https version:

```
https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

let's analyze 2nd situation:

```
http://example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

will be handled by first rule (https off) which will redirect to with https version:

```
https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and after will be handled by second rule which will add www. as prefix:

```
https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: seems like it happens by php scripts, I hope it's all from .htaccess? or You've other directives which does global rewrite?

Comment: @Z.Kirik try to remove from kod_bird folder that rules or update htaccess in that folder too

Comment: I examined the $ _SERVER array with PHP,
anyway when the protocol is https
No HTTPS parameter inside array $ _SERVER

Comment: @Z.Kirik well it means that mod php does not pass protocol attribute which may happen when AllowOverride is disabled in virtual host configs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php

Comment: so You can fix in php level to not check http or need to fix in apache configs

Comment: Can we say that the https redirect fails because apache does not allow changes?

Comment: @Z.Kirik 50/50 I don’t have full picture. app is laravel based or something custom? why not disable that custom stuff to not redirect? since we are doing already with apache