# Deny direct access to "Assets" folder by a user, but allow index.html to access it.

Tags: html, access-denied

I want to block direct access to the assets folder on my website which contains all my images, style sheets, and etc.

However, if I do this by a "DENY FROM ALL" command in a .htaccess file in the root "assets" folder, none of my pages can access the assets; which makes sense.

Is there anyway to allow website pages to access the files, but block a person who directly tries to access them (e.g., www.pburtchaell.com/assets/images/../)? Thanks!

Comment: Give this a shot? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281277/htaccess-allow-localhost-problem

Comment: It sounds fairly similar to your question.